# Is there a better way to stream output into html div than appending it with setInterval?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, optimization

I have a static page that simulates streaming text into HTML div. The code is

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
    // generate bio
    const bio = $('#template-bio')[0].innerHTML;
    const compiledBio = $('#compiled-bio');
    const verbatimBio = $('#verbatim-bio');
    let compiled = '';
    let verbatim = '';
    let compile = false;
    let index = 0;
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
      const symbol = bio[index++];
      if (index >= bio.length) {
        finishBioGeneration();
        return;
      }
      else if (compile && symbol == '>') {
        compiled += verbatim + symbol;
        compiledBio.html(compiled);
        verbatim = '';
        verbatimBio.text('');
        compile = false;
      } else {
        if (!compile && symbol == '<' && (bio[index] == '/' || bio[index] == 'b')) {
          compile = true;
        }
        verbatim += symbol;
        verbatimBio.append(symbol);
      }
    }, 50);
}
```

and appends symbols of a `template-bio` div into `verbatim-bio` div and occasionally compiles the generated code. Html is

```html
<div id='bio'>
   <span id='compiled-bio'></span><span id='verbatim-bio'></span>
</div>
<div id='template-bio'>
   ****text****
</div>
```

Sometimes when I run the page the text generation gets stuck and often times its speed is inconsistent. Is there a way to do this better?

Comment: Gets stuck because it tries to render html tags character by character.  `<` then `<d` … `<di` … `<div`, which has little or no visual effect.  Only “typewriter” the actual text and not the tag bits.

Comment: No, it gets stuck sometimes, not always. The not closed tags might be a problem but most browsers don't seem to mind.